# ajax datepicker jquery ui

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a table which should return values based on the date submitted. I want to make the datepicker send an ajax request to the server whenever the date has been changed. I am looking for a sample example to implement this. Thanks in advance..

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at documentation and Events section?

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ yourself first? SO is not here to write a complete solution for you.

Comment: I am sorry for the very basic question but I have read the events and methods, I am pretty new to jquery and still learning. I am trying to implement datepicker. If I would have understood and implemented it, I see no reason to post a question and get downvoted..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker(function() {
  onSelect: 
        function() {
          $.ajax(
            url: "yourURL",
            success: function(data) {
                  // your logic here
          }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    // your ajax request
  }
});
```